# Inaccessible operator == breaks child class with spaceship operator

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, c++20

I bumped in GCC error, which can be demonstrated with the following simplified program. Base struct `A` has an `operator ==` with some argument type other than `A`. Child struct `B` defines default spaceship `operator <=>`, which shall implicitly define `operator ==` as well. But since no appropriate equality operator is found in the base class, `B::operator ==` must be implicitly deleted. Instead, the resulting struct `B` appears broken in a way that no object of it can be created:

```
#include <compare>

struct A { 
    std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A &) const = default;
    bool operator==(int) const;
};

struct B : A { 
    virtual std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const B &) const noexcept = default;
};

B b; //GCC error here
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/584nhfxxs

Error message:

```
error: use of deleted function 'virtual constexpr bool B::operator==(const B&) const'
    9 |     virtual std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const B &) const noexcept = default;
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
<source>:9:34: note: 'virtual constexpr bool B::operator==(const B&) const' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
<source>:8:8: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'A' and 'A')
    8 | struct B : A {
      |        ^
<source>:5:10: note: candidate: 'bool A::operator==(int) const' (reversed)
    5 |     bool operator==(int) const;
      |          ^~~~~~~~
<source>:5:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'A' to 'int'
    5 |     bool operator==(int) const;
```

Is it simply a bug in GCC?

Comment: If it’s not a bug, what do you want to ask about this situation?  “No” doesn’t seem like a very helpful answer.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. `B`'s `operator==` should be defined as deleted, but that's... fine?